# Operations with window.open

Tags: javascript, html, window

I have a javascript code that opens a page by doing the following:
 `location.href("newPage.cfm?param1=xxx&param2=yyy");`

The "newPage" must return to the previous, passgin some parameters, like this:

`location.href("prevPage.cfm?param1=www&param2=kkk")`.

Now, I want to do the same thing, to open the newPage, using:

`window.open`

My question is: how can I return to the previous page, closing the new one (`window.close`), but passing the new parameters?

Comment: `window.opener` should hold the reference to the window the popup was opened from.

Comment: @SidCool not sure *Running a software team at Google* is particularly relevant to this question... :)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.  I posted the wrong link, what I intended was this one: 

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Comment: @SidCool, back will not address this issue either....He's opening a new window. The histories will be different. He wants to pass params in. Basically that's all wrong.

Comment: We can use the parent's window object, can't we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the previous window using `window.opener`. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

So you simply need to change your code to:

```
window.opener.location.href("prevPage.cfm?param1=www&param2=kkk");
window.close();
```

this is in your *opened* window.

Comment: w3schools is a terrible resourse. I offer this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener

Comment: Yea it's not great, first on the list. Showed what needed to be done...<shrug>

Answer (score 0):

you also use this.

```
<script language="javascript">
         window.opener.location = "prevPage.cfm?param1=www&param2=kkk";
         window.close();
</script>
```